# Waiting for observable until API Load all the information Angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I have been working in a loading component to make a friendly wait between the content is called and loaded from API. There is no issue when is just text, but when the information has images or more information, the loading component disappear before the content is fully loaded.

I took a look to the lifecycle hooks of Angular2, but any of them look like fit for my requirement.

Mainly my component understand when the isLoading = true have to disappear.

Here is my way I tried to do it.

```
ngOnInit() {
        // Payload to call the API
        var model: myPayload = {
            AuthorId: this._authorid,
            CountryId: this._countryid

        }
        // Api loading
        Observable.forkJoin(
            this._service.getList(model)
        )
            .subscribe(
            res => {
                this.authorList = res[0];
            },
            null,
            () => { 
                this.isLoading = false 
                }
            )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to make components wait for a `Promise` or `Observable`.

The router can be made to wait for `Observable` to complete with the `CanActivate` guard.

A simple workaround is to just add `*ngIf="data"` on the outermost element in the view.

Comment: Thanks Mate, always helpful!

Answer (score 0):

For others, this is how you write your canActivate function.

**In your router:**

```
// all your imports go here

const APP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomePageComponent, canActivate: [WaitForApiLoad] }
]

export const AppRouter = RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES);
```

**Create a new service WaitForApiLoad**

```
// all your imports go here

@Injectable()
export class WaitForApiLoad implements CanActivate
{

    private dataFromApi: any;

    canActivate(activatedRouteSnapshot: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, 
            routerStateSnapshot: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean>  
    {

        return
            this.myApiService
                .getData()
                .map( data => {
                    this.dataFromApi = data;
                    return true;
                });
    }

}
```